# Having problems getting the number of plays in a WordPress Playlist from an audio file

Tags: count, audio

I have already seen a similar post here: [How to get the number of times an audio file has been played](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168584/how-to-get-the-number-of-times-an-audio-file-has-been-played)

But the code provided by @bonger did not work for me.  I uploaded the new functions.php with the following code in it, and it does not show the play count on the media edit page under bitrate as it is supposed to.

It would be great to count the number of times an audio file is played in a playlist. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Adding the following code in a new PHP document in Dreamweaver there are syntax errors on line 2, 24, 59, and 62.

```
    <?php
add_action( 'wp_footer', function () {
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        (function ($) {
            var srcs = []; // Array of sources already sent to cut down on posts to server.
            $('audio.wp-audio-shortcode, .wp-audio-playlist audio').on('play', function (event) {
                // this.src should be the url (guid) of the audio file
                if (this.src && $.inArray(this.src, srcs) === -1) {
                    srcs.push(this.src);
                    $.post( '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>', {
                            action: 'wpse168584_audio_stats',
                            guid: this.src.replace(/\?.+$/, ''), // Remove any query vars.
                            nonce: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'wpse168584_audio_stats_' ); ?>'
                        }, null, 'json'
                    );
                }
            });
        })(jQuery);
    });
    </script>
    <?php
} );
function wpse168584_audio_stats() {
    $ret = array( 'error' => false );

    if ( ! check_ajax_referer( 'wpse168584_audio_stats_', 'nonce', false /*die*/ ) ) {
        $ret['error'] = __( 'Permission error', 'wpfm' );
    } else {
        if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['guid'] ) || ! ( $guid = $_REQUEST['guid'] ) ) {
            $ret['error'] = __( 'Params error', 'wpfm' );
        } else {
            global $wpdb;
            $sql = $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT ID FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' WHERE guid = %s LIMIT 1', $guid );
            if ( $post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $sql ) ) {
                // Use hex format to save space, 8 bytes for IPv4, 32 for IPv6.
                $ip = bin2hex( inet_pton( preg_replace( '/[^0-9a-fA-F:., ]/', '', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) ) );
                if ( ! ( $meta = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_attachment_metadata', true ) )
                || ! isset( $meta['plays_ips'] )
                || ! in_array( $ip, $plays_ips = explode( ';', $meta['plays_ips'] ) ) ) {
                    $plays_ips[] = $ip;
                    // If data getting too big, drop off oldest ip (FIFO).
                    if ( strlen( $meta['play_ids'] ) > 1000 ) array_shift( $plays_ips );
                    // Save as string to save space.
                    $meta['plays_ips'] = implode( ';', $plays_ips );
                    $meta['plays'] = isset( $meta['plays'] ) ? $meta['plays'] + 1 : 1;
                    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_attachment_metadata', $meta );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    wp_send_json( $ret );
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpse168584_audio_stats', 'wpse168584_audio_stats' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpse168584_audio_stats', 'wpse168584_audio_stats' );

add_filter( 'media_submitbox_misc_sections', function ( $arr ) {
    $arr['plays'] = __( 'Play Count:' );
    return $arr;
} );
?>
```

Comment: Do you see any javascript errors? Do you know if it is failing on client side or server side?

Comment: @czerspalace it shows errors when I input the code in the functions.php file.

Comment: What do the errors say?

Comment: There are errors on the first line that says add_action to the line before function wpse168584_audio_stats() The same with the last bit of code that says add_filter( 'media_submitbox_misc_sections', function ( $arr ) ...there are errors on the first and last line of that code.

Comment: Please file an [edit] and explain in that [edit] what exactly is not working. Simply adding *not working* means nothing as *not working* can mean a million things. Please be exact

Comment: @PieterGoosen not sure how to file an edit. I tried to add a comment on the original post and it says I have to have so many points to comment. So I did what I could do which is ask my own question. If you know of a solution please help.

Comment: Asking a new question is correct. Linking to the original code is also correct. What I'm saying is, you said in your question here that the solution is not working, what is not working. What I have asked you to do is to click on the edit link to **this** question you have posted, or click **this** [edit], and add an explanation inside your question and tell us exactly what is not working. What you have posted in comments is not readable and also what you talked about getting errors, what are those errors. Without this info, your question will go unanswered

Comment: @PieterGoosen thanks for your input. I have edited the question

Comment: The syntax is fine. Exactly what does the errors say

Comment: @PieterGoosen In Dreamweaver it just says syntax errors on those lines, it does not expound upon the errors.

Comment: have you tried to run this code in a browser?

Comment: It has to tell you exactly what the error is, it can't just say "syntax error on line x". These messages are more explicit than that. Anyway, as I said, syntax look fine as is working. You either have an extra php tag or are missing one, or you have an ancient PHP version, which in any case, if your PHP version is older that 5.3, the code above will not work. Just a note, support for PHP 5.3 was dropped almost a year ago, so that means, if you don't have at least 5.4, your site have huge security risk and will be hacked if a hacker gets their hands on your site

Comment: @PieterGoosen I am not speaking of an error on the server which by the way is up to date. I am saying that Dreamweaver says there is a syntax error on lines 2, 24, 59, and 62. Are you familiar with Adobe Dreamweaver? It is a program or web design and development application. If you don't have it then perhaps you won't understand what I am saying. If Dreamweaver sees an error in the code I'm not uploading it to my server until the errors are corrected. If you can't help. I understand.

Comment: @czerspalace I'm sorry I missed your comment amongst the negative comments spewed from the other guy. I uploaded the new functions.php with the code from above in it, and it does not show the play count on the media edit page under bitrate as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

The code requires at least PHP 5.3. Dreamweaver [does not support that PHP version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224374/dreamweaver-cs5-code-hinting-and-syntax-errors-with-php-5-4), so it reports unknown, newer syntax as errors.

WordPress [requires just version 5.2.4, but it recommends at least 5.4](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/). My suggestion is to use always the latest stable version on the server, currently PHP 5.6. Your development setup should use exactly the same version as the server to avoid portability problems.
Upload a file with just `<?php echo PHP_VERSION; ?>` in it and look at it in a browser to see the version.

Then you have to find a better editor. You have multiple options:

- Switch to the new subscription based version of Dreamweaver.
- [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/). Most professional developers use that nowadays. It is not free, but it comes with many features, including WordPress support and the option to select a project specific PHP version.
- Use another IDE like [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/pdt/) or [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/features/php/index.html).
- Use an Editor like [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/) or [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/). Both need a bunch of plugins to make your work comfortable.

If you have problems on the server, enable the [debug mode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), and install [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/). This will tell you what the error says and where it comes from.

Comment: Being a moderator does not give you the right to delete my comments and then posting what I have said in comments in your answer. And please don't tell me that my comments was rude, offensive or out of place.

Comment: @PieterGoosen That discussion belongs to [meta]. The proper use of development tools is **on topic** on our site. Rude comments are not welcome. Neither are targeted votes btw.

Comment: Thomas I'm not in the mood for this, neither am I in the mood for any type of fight. BTW, I'm leaving and will not be available for the rest of the day. My downvote is **NOT** to target you or meant in ill spirit, but for deleting my comments and using what I have said in comments in your answer, nothing more. If you feel offended by that, then you should may be post a new thread on [meta].

Comment: @PieterGoosen Whatever has been said in a comment can be used by anyone in an answer. That’s not just allowed, it is welcome. Besides that, what I wrote in my answer is **not** part of any comment, deleted or not.

Comment: @toscho Thank you so much for explaining in detail. I have added the php echo file to my server and I am using version 5.4.40. I have realized what the problem is. I will post an answer to my question. Also thank you for the information on some alternate editors, I always use Dreamweaver because that is what I started with years ago, but it may be time for a change, lol. Thanks a mil.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @czerspalace and @toshco for helping me do some troubleshooting to figure out what the problem was.

Once you upload the new functions.php file with the play count code in it, you will not see the play count in the save box under bit rate immediately, it does not show at all if the play count is 0. The code works, but will only show after the file is played at least 1 time, and not if it has played 1 time before you uploaded the code, but played at least 1 time after the code is in your functions.php file.

Comment: Please do not add "the answer worked"-answers. Instead tick the check mark below the voting arrows on the left upper side of an answer that helped you. Thanks.

Comment: The answers they gave me helped me rule out possible problems. No one told me the answer, therefore I wrote the answer to help other people that may think the code didn't work. It only shows after the file has been played, which is what I said, no one else had that input. Thanks @kaiser.

Comment: Yes, but if you add an answer, please make sure that it helps a later reader to fix the problem.

Comment: @kaiser That's exactly what I did. I wrote the answer to help future readers.

Comment: Sorry, but this should be an [edit] to the question instead.