# Trying to get the number of times an audio file has been played

Tags: audio

I have a small number of MP3 files on my site and I want to track the number of times the play button is pressed.    I am using the inbuilt Wordpress MP3 player and have inserted the file by using media within the text editing area so I have:

> [audio mp3="https://staging.modburyteam.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Weekly-reflection-22nd-March.mp3"][/audio]

Within the `functions.php` file in my child theme I have the following:

```php
add_action( 'wp_footer', function () {
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        (function ($) {
            var srcs = []; // Array of sources already sent to cut down on posts to server.
            $('audio.wp-audio-shortcode, .wp-audio-playlist audio').on('play', function (event) {
                // this.src should be the url (guid) of the audio file
                if (this.src && $.inArray(this.src, srcs) === -1) {
                    srcs.push(this.src);
                    $.post( '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>', {
                            action: 'wpse168584_audio_stats',
                            guid: this.src.replace(/\?.+$/, ''), // Remove any query vars.
                            nonce: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'wpse168584_audio_stats_' ); ?>'
                        }, null, 'json'
                    );
                }
            });
        })(jQuery);
    });
    </script>
    <?php
} );
function wpse168584_audio_stats() {
    $ret = array( 'error' => false );

    if ( ! check_ajax_referer( 'wpse168584_audio_stats_', 'nonce', false /*die*/ ) ) {
        $ret['error'] = __( 'Permission error', 'wpfm' );
    } else {
        if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['guid'] ) || ! ( $guid = $_REQUEST['guid'] ) ) {
            $ret['error'] = __( 'Params error', 'wpfm' );
        } else {
            global $wpdb;
            $sql = $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT ID FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' WHERE guid = %s LIMIT 1', $guid );
            if ( $post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $sql ) ) {
                // Use hex format to save space, 8 bytes for IPv4, 32 for IPv6.
                $ip = bin2hex( inet_pton( preg_replace( '/[^0-9a-fA-F:., ]/', '', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) ) );
                if ( ! ( $meta = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_attachment_metadata', true ) )
                || ! isset( $meta['plays_ips'] )
                || ! in_array( $ip, $plays_ips = explode( ';', $meta['plays_ips'] ) ) ) {
                    $plays_ips[] = $ip;
                    // If data getting too big, drop off oldest ip (FIFO).
                    if ( strlen( $meta['play_ids'] ) > 1000 ) array_shift( $plays_ips );
                    // Save as string to save space.
                    $meta['plays_ips'] = implode( ';', $plays_ips );
                    $meta['plays'] = isset( $meta['plays'] ) ? $meta['plays'] + 1 : 1;
                    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_attachment_metadata', $meta );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    wp_send_json( $ret );
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpse168584_audio_stats', 'wpse168584_audio_stats' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpse168584_audio_stats', 'wpse168584_audio_stats' );

add_filter( 'media_submitbox_misc_sections', function ( $arr ) {
    $arr['plays'] = __( 'Play Count:' );
    return $arr;
} );
```

I did expect that the number of times the play button was clicked would show up in the read only area if I edit the media file, but nothing is appearing.

Can some kind person tell me where I am going wrong please?

Many thanks

A.

Comment: Is there a reason you went with the legacy old Admin AJAX API for the AJAX request instead of the modern REST API? Note that like tracking post views with post meta, this will be prone to undercounting and race conditions, your stats will be highly unreliable when your site gets more than a few concurrent visitors. I also see your functions are prefixed with WPSE question IDs, can you link us to the original source of the code? If you're using an analytics service such as Google Analytics, you can fire off events that are tracked by those services too, there's no need to self-collect the data

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168584/how-to-get-the-number-of-times-an-audio-file-has-been-played

Comment: The code I used was already posted here from about 18 months ago, when someone else had exactly the same issue,  the original source code url has already been posted  above by Nathan.   Given that we are using an inbuilt audio player within our Wordpress theme, I was unaware that Analytics would be able to track that.  We do use this so will investigate.  Thanks